# Changing text font size adaptively in beamer slides

Tags: beamer, formatting

In Beamer, I want slides with less text to appear bigger and those with more text to have smaller font size. Moreover, if I cut some text from a particular slide, rest of the text should appear bigger. Is this possible?

In powerpoint, we can increase text size by stretching the frame/ block containing the text.

Comment: I was wondering this as well. Not only to fit more text (that may be not recommendable for most presentations) but for enlarging when possible. I think it is not possible or very difficult but I am not a Beamer expert. 
Nevertheless, using \vfill among items may improve appearance.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the beamer user guide:

> Never use a smaller font size to “fit more on a frame.” Never ever use the evil option `shrink`.

Example:

```
\begin{frame}[shrink=5]
   Some evil endless slide that is 5\% too large.
\end{frame}
```